# Recursive Tree not giving correct output

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, tree

I have a tree object which has two children(subTree) 5 and 6. 5 has another children 7 and 6 has another children 8. I want to find if any particular subtree is contained in the tree. For example, I have written a function that will return if subtree 8 is present in the tree.

```
var tree = {
  value: undefined,
  children: [{
    value: 5,
    children: [{
      value: 7,
      children: []
    }]
  }, {
    value: 6,
    children: [{
      value: 8,
      children: []
    }]
  }]
};
```

My recursive function:

```
  var contains = function (node, target) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      if (node.children[i].value === target) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return contains(node.children[i], target);
      }
      return false;

    }
  };
contains(tree, 8);
```

As we can see, 8 is present in the tree, but my function is returning false. My function returns true if I want to check if 5 or 7 is present, but it returns undefined if I call it to search for 6 or 8. I tried with the debugger, it shows my code does not increment the for loop to check the next children after 5. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your `return false` should maybe be outside of the `for` loop

Comment: `return false` is never executed, but the point is right: you always return in the first iteration of the loop, so there is not much iteration happening.

Comment: @TKoL I moved the return false outside the for a loop.  But still not showing true for 6 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

I've shifted some of your code around so it doesn't `return` prematurely

```js
var tree = {
  value: undefined,
  children: [{
    value: 5,
    children: [{
      value: 7,
      children: []
    }]
  }, {
    value: 6,
    children: [{
      value: 8,
      children: []
    }]
  }]
};

var contains = function (node, target) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      if (node.children[i].value === target) {
        return true;
      } else {
        if(contains(node.children[i], target)) return true;
      }
     

    }
     return false;
};

console.log(contains(tree, 8));
```

Comment: It is working fine now. Thank you very much. As I am still learning, would you mind sharing why did you think it that way? What was wrong with my approach? Is there any mindset that I should follow while doing this kind of problem?

Comment: @AshequlHaque recursive functions are still a bit of a difficult thing to explain or even think about sometimes, I don't have any quick words. In my comment on your original question, I just ran through it in my head and that's how I noticed the `return false` was happening too soon -- I noticed immediately that all paths were returning before you even processed the second item in the array, which is exactly where the `8` was!

Comment: @AshequlHaque that's one of the important bits that you have to get good at in general, not just for recursive functions: learn how to run the program in your head. Know which line of code is getting processed after each other line of code under various conditions. Become the computer.